# ember.js parentController property is not set in itemController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a basic requirement and I am unable to figure this out. Any help would be great.

I have an Array of Edms (EdmsController) that contains individual Edm (EdmController).

This is what I define:

```
window.CMS.EdmsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'edm'

window.CMS.EdmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend Ember.Evented,
```

In the EdmController, after adding a new EDM, I want to add it to the content in the parentController.

But

```
@get('parentController') is null in the EdmController.
```

What am I missing?  Why isn't the parentController being set?

This is how I access it.

```
  actions:
    new_edm: ->
      console.log('save_edm called')
        options = {
          url: 'cms2/new_edm',
          type:'post',
          dataType:'json',
          beforeSubmit:beforeSubmit,
          success:(responseText,statusText,xhr,$form) =>
            window.bootstrap_alert.warning('EDM successfully saved')
            object = responseText
            console.log(this)
            parentController = @get('parentController')
            console.log(parentController)
            content = parentController.get('content')
            content.pushObject(object)
          error:error}
          console.log(options)
          $('#edm_form').ajaxSubmit(options)
```

Comment: Can you show where you are accessing this property?

Comment: @MarcioJunior Sorry, I should have added it.  I use jquery.form.js plugin to submit the form (multipart-form with images).  I access the parentController in the success callback as shown above.

Please note that the => in the success handler gives access the controller object correctly (it handles scope correctly)

Comment: What is the value of this on the console.log statement. Is it the controller?

Comment: @GauravShetty yes, it's the controller (and not jQuery ajax object).

Comment: How do you setup your EdmsController ? How did you "add the new EDM"? The answer will lie there.